# Buscar un valor en un array con vuejs

Tags: javascript, array, component, vuejs

** Agregue mas informacion 
Del lado del backend estoy enviando los datos de los usuarios de mi sistema de esta forma

```
public function getusers()
{
    return User::where('status','habilitado')
        ->with('roles')
        ->with('person.positions')
        ->with('person.area')
        ->where('status', 'habilitado')
        ->get();
}
```

y esto lo estoy llamando con una peticion axios

que es esta

```
   getUsers(){
       var urlUsers= "getusers";
       axios.get(urlUsers).then(response=>{
       this.users = response.data;
       this.mytable()
   });
```

Y lo estoy enviando a una tabla que la organizo con datatables, ,el asunto es que necesito validar en el v-for de la grilla si el usuario tiene el rol de administrador, y eso so puedo averiguar identificando si el usuario tiene en el rol, el "slug" de administrador, el v-for es el siguiente

```
<tr v-for= "(user, index)  in users" :key="index">
```

Este es el array completo de uno de los usuario que genero

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dni": "11.111.111-1",
    "name": "JORGE EL CURIOSO",
    "email": "CORREO@EMAIL.CL",
    "status": "habilitado",
    "created_at": "2019-06-27 16:21:16",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-27 16:21:16",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Locked",
        "slug": "locked",
        "description": "Usuario bloqueado sin acceso a ningun modulo con permisos del sistema",
        "created_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
        "special": "no-access",
        "pivot": {
          "user_id": 1,
          "role_id": 4,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Control de Costos de Obra",
        "slug": "control-de-costos-de-obra",
        "description": "Usuario de costos de obra",
        "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
        "special": null,
        "pivot": {
          "user_id": 1,
          "role_id": 24,
          "created_at": "2019-11-11 18:48:42",
          "updated_at": "2019-11-11 18:48:42"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Saludos Enrique, espero estés bien, la pregunta del millón: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: En el componente he intentado buscar de esta forma {{ user.roles.indexOf(1)}}

Comment: coloca todo lo que has realizado y todo el código necesario para que sea fácil de reproducir tu escenario y obtengas una respuesta de calidad :D

Comment: A que te refieres con buscar? A saber si existe dicho valor? O como?

Comment: En todo caso la búsqueda la debes saber implementar sobre un objeto, ya que `slug` es la propiedad de un objeto. Primero busca la forma de encontrar valores en objetos en JavaScript. Cuando tengas eso, podrás continuar para realizar la búsqueda dentro de un `array` de objetos. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, agregue mas información, lo que necesito en realidad es poder consultar al objeto, si se encuentra el slug "administrador"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues parece que lo lógico es loopear hasta encontrar, como toda la vida en JS, pues no deja de ser JSON.

***Échale un ojo a***:

[Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)

> Mira los siguientes ejemplos:

- ***Si quieres nada mas el value Locked***

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Locked",
    "slug": "locked",
    "description": "Usuario bloqueado sin acceso a ningun modulo con permisos del sistema",
    "created_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "special": "no-access",
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 4,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Control de Costos de Obra",
    "slug": "control-de-costos-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario de costos de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 24,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Administrativo de Obra",
    "slug": "administrativo-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario administrativo de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 25,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41"
    }
  }
]

for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
  var slug  = myArray[i].slug;
  if (slug == "locked" || slug == "Locked") {
  document.body.innerHTML = slug;
  }
}
```

- ***Si quieres el objeto completo***

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Locked",
    "slug": "locked",
    "description": "Usuario bloqueado sin acceso a ningun modulo con permisos del sistema",
    "created_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "special": "no-access",
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 4,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Control de Costos de Obra",
    "slug": "control-de-costos-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario de costos de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 24,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Administrativo de Obra",
    "slug": "administrativo-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario administrativo de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 25,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41"
    }
  }
]

for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
  var slug  = myArray[i].slug;
  if (slug == "locked" || slug == "Locked") {
  document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArray[i], null, 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas, un saludo.

> ***EDIT:***

Como comente, aunque estés utilizando Vue, no deja de ser JS y aunque no estas mostrando lo que verdaderamente importa (que es tu archivo js donde esta tu componente de vueJs) me tome la molestia de realizarte un ejemplo de como puedes filtrar un valor dentro de un objeto anidado dentro de un array (ya explicado arribaa) e introducirlo a tu datatable con vue:

```js
var updatebtn = document.querySelector("#update");
var myArray = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Locked",
    "slug": "locked",
    "description": "Usuario bloqueado sin acceso a ningun modulo con permisos del sistema",
    "created_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-27 16:20:36",
    "special": "no-access",
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 4,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Control de Costos de Obra",
    "slug": "control-de-costos-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario de costos de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 24,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:44"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Administrativo de Obra",
    "slug": "administrativo-de-obra",
    "description": "Usuario administrativo de obra",
    "created_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-11 14:16:34",
    "special": null,
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 63,
      "role_id": 25,
      "created_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-11 15:04:41"
    }
  }
]

var grid = new Vue({
  el: '#grid',
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (value) {
      if (!value) return ''
      value = value.toString()
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
    }
  },
  data: {
    cols: ["name","slug","id"],
    items: [
      { name: 'Jose', slug:"standby", id:46 },
      { name: 'Juan', slug:"pass", id:12 }
    ]
  }
});


updatebtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  updateItems(myArray)
});



function updateItems(array) {
  for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    var slug  = myArray[i].slug;
    if (slug == "locked" || slug == "Locked") {
      grid.items.push(myArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color:rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.66);
}

th {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.66);
  border: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#update {
 background-color: white;
 border: solid 2px rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.66);
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<table id="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="i in cols">
        {{i | capitalize }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="i in items">
      <td>
        {{i.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{i.slug}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{i.id}}
      </td>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="update">Actualizar</button>
```

De nuevo espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Pero esa lógica entiendo que debe ir en un método, ¿como puedo incorporar u obtener ese resultado en la grilla?

Comment: Hola enrique, he actualizado la respuesta, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias compañero es justo lo que necesitaba lo probe y funciona!